# Crop multiple pages in a pdf file

Tags: pdf, preview, crop

I can use Preview app to select a region and crop a page. Can I do the same cropping for a whole pages in pdf? Are there tools (commercial or free) available for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got a hint that works from [this page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009020813122640)

1. Using the *Sidebar*, make it *Thumbnails* view, and *Select All* pages (Cmd-A)
2. Select the area to crop using *Tools* > *Rectangular Select*
3. Do the *Tools* > *Crop* (Cmd-K)

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but if that works, sick.

Comment: @hobs : It works, I checked that.

Comment: Useful hints to go along with this: (1) Right click in the thumbnail view and select `columns -> 2` to display 2 columns of thumbnails. This allows you to easily select all the even or odd pages, which can be useful if you need to crop them differently. (2) Open the ruler tab of the inspector to see details on what you are cropping.

Comment: @nathang: Thanks for the hint, it's exactly what I wanted to do. The really sad thing is that Apple keeps removing features from its softwares to optimize for the most stupid users. They don't want to confuse them with perfectly functioning and useful stuff. The multi column option of the thumbnail view has fallen victim to this over-simplification for which I really hate them. Thankfully I've never upgraded(?) my old laptop still running OSX 10.6 with Preview 5.0.3 still having this feature. May all 1-button Apple mouse and other over-simplified unusable "designer" hw/sw burn in hell!!! :D

Comment: This answer does not work in Mountaion Lion. Any workarounds?

Comment: @BartArondson: it still works for me, under Mountain Lion, except that the thumbnails are now in the left sidebar. You can get them to display by selecting [View] -> [Thumbnails] (Command-option-2).

Comment: @PLL Suddenly it does... Thank you, I must've been doing something stupid.

Comment: Cropping only even or odd pages is still possible in OS X 10.10, it's just a bit more cumbersome: (1) Select "View -> Contact Sheet". (2) Zoom in and make the window narrow so that you get two columns. (3) Start dragging over one of the columns (you'll get a rectangle selection) and while holding the mouse button down, press Fn+Down to scroll all the way down. Now one entire column should be selected. (4) Select "View -> Thumbnails" to switch back. (5) Crop as described in this answer. It will crop only the even or odd pages.

Comment: I just figured this method out myself and came to Ask to share, only to find it's already here. This method also keeps the size of the PDF largely the same, compared to other methods (PDFpen, pdfcrop) which can double the size of the PDF.