# How to remove page marks in pdf file with iPad viewers?

Tags: ipad, pdf, preview, crop

I found some of the pdf files has some page marks(or three holes I don't know the official name for the marks) as is shown:

[image]

Most of the iPad pdf viewers can't recognize this to show the marks, only the [good reader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) app can show only the area inside the marks. I wanted to stick to the good reader, but it sometimes doesn't show the pages properly, so I need to find a way.

I was trying to use crop method : [Crop multiple pages in a pdf file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/crop-multiple-pages-in-a-pdf-file) to cut out the marks in Mac, but Mac pdf viewers (Preview, Skim) are smart enough to show the region inside the marks.

Do you know any way to resolve this issue?

- Do you know how to show the marks so that I can crop them?
- Do you know any smart iPad pdf reader that shows the region inside the marks?

Comment: They are registration and bleed marks for printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just could use [Crop multiple pages in a pdf file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/crop-multiple-pages-in-a-pdf-file) method to remove the bleed marks. I cropped the original pdf book by making the cropping area the same as the page that is shown.

After the cropping the file size became 6.1MB from 3.8MB, but it didn't matter to me.