# Is it possible to crop multiple pages in Mavericks Preview.app?

Tags: macos, preview

Is it possible to crop multiple pages or image files in the new Mavericks Preview application just as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14739/24324)?

The functionality was there with Snow Leopard but disappeared in Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only possible when editing a pdf. It isn't possible to apply a single crop to many images that are in separate files. In order to do this, one way would be to

1. Combine the images into a single pdf

   - Open all of them in a single window.
   - Use "Print" then "Save as pdf."
2. Use the technique described in the [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110361/93168) to crop all pages of the resultant pdf.
3. Split the images back out into separate files using a variety of techniques, such as Automator's "Render PDF Pages as Images" function, or on the command line using ImageMagick as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/243712).

Note: if you're willing to use the command line, you might just want to use [ImageMagick directly](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) to crop all of the images.

Comment: There's already an accepted answer with instructions on how to do this, so clearly it does work -- maybe you'd like to elaborate on why you think it doesn't?

Comment: I accepted the answer at the time as there was nothing else around. However, the answer of Kio Dane is only applicable to a pdf file, where I asked `pages or files`. So Idin K's answer goes more into detail (it treats both a single pdf and a series of image files) . I'm still not on Mavericks myself so can't check it. I've unaccepted the answer to consider different answers.

Comment: This does not work. Preview only hides the "cropped" part of PDF files, but not actually crop it. After the PDF is rendered back to images, the cropped part  reappears.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.

1. Open a PDF.
2. If not already enabled, *View* → *Thumbnails*.
3. Select some pages (click first then select all; <kbd>command</kbd>+click or <kbd>shift</kbd>+click)
4. Use the rectangle tool to select region on page. (On versions of OS X prior to 10.9, you should see a preview of the selection on other pages too).
5. Select *Tools* → **Crop** (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). All your selected pages should be cropped.
6. Save or Save As.

Comment: it's cropping only the first image, why is that ?